# glew not initializing with SDL2

Tags: c++, opengl-3, glew, sdl-2

I've been trying to get **GLew 1.10** to play nicely with **SDL 2.0.3**, but GLew won't initialize. 
The problem I'm having is that GLew 1.10 requires a function `GLEWContext* glewGetContext().`

I've tried to use a the same solution used for GLew 1.10 with GLFW3, where you use a `struct` to handle the window and GLew context, but that method doesn't work with SDL2.

The 2 errors I'm receiving is this which points to glewInit():

`C3861: 'glewGetContext': identifier not found`

`Intellisense: identifier "glewGetContext is undefined`

**code:**

```
    // Create window
    _screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    /* Create Context */
    _mainContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_screen);

    /* swap syncronized */
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(0);

    // Initialize GLew 1.10
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum glewError = glewInit(); <------------- error

    if (glewError != GLEW_OK)
        printf("Error with GLew. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
```

Comment: Are these runtime errors or compile errors?

Comment: @TalesM as soon as I type it, the error shows. It requires the GLEWContext* function, but just like I said earlier, the GLFW3 way doesn't work for SDL2.